# How to encrypt index data in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to index the text of some books in my application to be searchable by Elastic. Because the text must be highlighted, i should allow Elastic to store text in the filesystem.

My problem is that the text must be protected from accessing out of the application, because the books have Copyrights. I can store main data in an encrypted sqlite db, but how can tell elastic to encrypt it in its index data too?

**Note:** The application must be worked completely offline. So i can not use the Client/Server model.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, Elasticsearch does not encrypt its index data.

If you need to limit the access to your index on elasticsearch you can use a plugin like Search Guard, which has Index-level security in the Community Version.

You can also look into the Security feature from Elastic, but you need a paid license for that.

Comment: Thanks, can your suggestion (Search Guard and Security feature) solve my problem?